# Install spark.streaming.twitter Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to do a project where we read tweets from twitter every second. I am using Intellij and have imported most of the jars. I have one error on import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.*;.
I am using Windows
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. I found the correct libraries in Bahir http://bahir.apache.org/downloads/spark/